# Getting all kinds of weird POST requests over localtunnel

Tags: localtunnel

I'm developing a Rails app on my local machine right now and I've put it on localtunnel a number of times today.

Each time I do, I get a whole bunch of strange POST requests to my server. Some examples:

```
/callbacks/geo/san-francisco

/facebook/subscription

/webhooks

/stripe-events
```

What's going on here!? Is someone trying to launch an attack my firing off a ton of requests to randomly-generated localtunnel URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 6700 or so unique localtunnel URL's, and people misconfigure their apps to continue to send requests even after they are done using the URL. This is fairly common when using Localtunnel.

You should upgrade to localtunnel v2, which has much stronger uniqueness requirements and should eliminate the random traffic.